# Debug в pgAdmin под windows

Tags: postgresql, отладка, plpgsql, pgadmin4

Операционная система windows_10 (64bit), бд postgresql-12, pgadmin4 v6.10. Через pgAdmin запросы к базе и функции работают. Проблема с опцией `Debug`. Если правой кнопкой по рабочей функции вызвать `Debugging -> Set Breakpoint`, то откроется закладка данной функции в окне программы и в её центре надпись: `"Waiting for another session to invoke the target"` с режимом ожидания навечно. Если вызвать `Debugging -> Debug`, то откроется закладка с кнопками управления и функционалом как ожидается. Но движение `Step` по коду всегда зависает примерно  через минуту и всё блокируется, например на 30-ом шаге, - или на 50-ом, если проходить быстро.
Если вместо `Step` нажать `Start`, то весь код функции выполняется без проблем. Из того, что
вижу по pgAdmin 4: `File -> Runtime -> View log`

```
  ...

  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 5050
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  ...

  - SESSIONNAME: Console
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
  - windir: C:\Windows
 --------------------------------------------------------

 2023-05-16 12:34:06,492: WARNING   werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.

 * Serving Flask app 'pgadmin' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

Если замечание `WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance` из лога имеет отношение к описанной проблеме, то нашёл такую ссылку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991897/websocket-transport-not-available-install-eventlet-or-gevent-and-gevent-websock
но по рекомендации Miguel Grinberg данного топика есть отзывы в других источниках, что не помогло в решении проблемы, кроме того я не понял сути. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Вы находили рекомендации сопряженные с установкой библиотеки необходимой для реализации устойчивого обмена через websocket: simple-websocket? Почему вы используете шестую версию, зависящую от возможностей имеющихся на борту браузеров? Все сводится по сути к недостатку функциональных возможностей используемой среды исполнения, обеспечивающей поддержку накладных операций пошаговой отладки.